# Python Plot doesn't appear when launched by Command Line in C#

Tags: c#, python, matplotlib, command

I am trying to launch python script from a simple C# application with a command line (I can't use packages like IronPython). It works perfectly since I can see all the print command executed on the console. The problem arises when it comes to show a matplotlib plot, nothing appears but following lines are executed...

Here is how I launch my python script from C# :

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();

cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Anaconda3\\python.exe C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\test.py");
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
Console.ReadKey();
```

And the python script is only:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("OK!!")

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()

print("Done")
```

When I launch it by myself in the command prompt, it works fine. 
Has anyone already got this issue? Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** When adding plt.savefig('foo.png'), the plot is saved! But I still would like it to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of how to do this using `pythonnet` in [`scriptcs`](http://scriptcs.net/) console:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/442

```
> #r "C:\Python\Anaconda3_64b\Lib\site-packages\Python.Runtime.dll";
> using Python.Runtime;
> PythonEngine.Initialize();
> dynamic mpl = Py.Import("matplotlib");
> mpl.use("TkAgg")
> dynamic plt = Py.Import("matplotlib.pyplot");
> plt.plot(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The final goal is to embed it into a WPF application, will it be possible with this?

Comment: it depends on complexity of your WPF app, but here is a small demo: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/demo/DynamicGrid.py